# Unable to update existing App in App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode10.1

I wish to update my existing app in the app store but there is a message displayed on the screen after creating .ipa file:

> Missing private keys.

How can I get the key(s)?

Comment: i think you implement push notification in your application , and i think you get the certificate and Provisioning Profile from other system.
Am i right ?

Comment: Yes. How can I get the certificate to the current system? May you please help me.

Comment: You have 2 options to do. 
1- Create Certificate on your system, install and use those.
2- Ask that person to give you .p12 file of the certificate (Export certificate with Key)